# jQuery create tabbed content problem

Tags: jquery, split, element, tabbed

The idea is to rewrite original HTML (on the fly) and create tabbed content instead. So let's say we have something like:

```
<div id="tabber">
<h1>Tab one</h1>
...HTML text 1...
<h1>Tab two</h1>
...HTML text 2...
<h1>Tab three</h1>
...HTML text 3...
</div>
```

The above code should end up in form like:

```
<div id="tabber">
<ul>
<li class="tabbertab">Tab one</li>
<li class="tabbertab">Tab two</li>
<li class="tabbertab">Tab three</li>
</ul>
<div class="tabberdiv">...HTML text 1...</div>
<div class="tabberdiv">...HTML text 2...</div>
<div class="tabberdiv">...HTML text 3...</div>
</div>
```

So I've tried to use something like this to kinda turn all of H1 to tab labels and the content between next H1 to tab content:

```
var menu_items = [];
var all_content = jQuery( '#tabber' ).html();
jQuery( all_content )
    .filter( 'h1' )
    .each( function() {
        menu_items.push( {
            title: jQuery( this ).text(),
            contents: jQuery( this ).nextUntil( 'h1' ).map( function() {
                return jQuery( this ).html();
            } ).get()
        } );
    } );
```

...more code will actually split objects saved in **menu_items** array and create clickable tabs that are supposed to show (hide) corresponding content.

The problem is that all of "major" HTML tags are stripped from **tabberdiv** DIV content. For example, H2, TABLE, UL, P, DIV ... none of it exist if used. However, A, LI, TR, TD are still there.

I was wondering what could be wrong with above chunk of jQuery code, which function causes disappearing HTML elements.

Thanks in advance!

========== A little bit later ==========

For some reason html() function is stripping down all of parent nodes. I'm not a jQuery expert and I guess there must be a reason for that.
Either way, a simple workaround would be the following:

```
jQuery( all_content )
    .filter( 'h1' )
    .each( function() {
        menu_items.push( {
            title: jQuery( this ).text(),
            contents: jQuery( this ).nextUntil( 'h1' ).map( function() {
                return '<' + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '>' + jQuery( this ).html() + '</' + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '>';
            } ).get()
        } );
} );
```